# How do I provide AWS credentials to Kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm setting up a Kubernetes cluster on AWS and as part of the configuration for say the API Server, I provide the `--cloud-provider=aws` setting.

Once it starts up, however, I see in the logs that it complains about not having AWS credentials:
`NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain`

After some searching, it seems that this issue was resolved for most people by using the "kube-up" script. However, for those who are not using the script to set up their cluster, how do we provide Kubernetes with AWS credentials?

Comment: I don't know enough about the AWS setup to help directly, but you could look through the kube-up function (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/util.sh#L674) and see if anything obvious jumps out at you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the appropriate IAM instance profile set on your master VM. The `kube-up` script for AWS creates a [role](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/templates/iam/kubernetes-master-role.json) and associated [policy](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/templates/iam/kubernetes-master-policy.json) that is attached to the master VM when it is created. Having the IAM policy attached should give you the credentials necessary to make API calls into AWS.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you! Looks like I forgot to update this question but you are correct. It seems like the EC2 instance needed to have the correct IAM profile set up. 

For anyone interested in what the IAM profile looked like, this is what I used for the master nodes (if you search for this you'll find similar variations of it that other people have used in their Kubernetes setup):

https://gist.github.com/lu4nm3/4d70863b2e251fe59a00